# What is "the sound of" mean in English?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I listened a dialog from IELTS that was

> RECEPTIONIST: Yes, we operate several tours up the coast. Where in particular did you wan to go?
>
> CUSTOMER: Well, I like **the sound of** the holiday that mentioned whales. Was it 'Whale Watching'?

So, What is "the sound of" mean in English? Is it widely used in oral English?

Comment: See [*sound*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sound): "9. *link verb* - When you are describing your impression or opinion of something you have heard about or read about, you can talk about the way it *sounds*."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your phrase is often used.

> The sound of

is a phrase meaning *the description of*, usually colocated with "*like*" or "*don't like*"

> The steak is thick and juicy and cooked to a succulent texture.
>   I like the sound of that!
>   *The description of the steak is tasty, I want to have some!*